# How to find high tech hotels in Hong Kong?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, hong-kong

I've heard stories about Hong Kong hotels that'll [give you a phone at check in that you'll later use to unlock the door to your room and you can also use it as a free hotspot](https://travgear.com/2016/04/25/review-iclub-sheung-wan-hotel-hong-kong/) when in the town and it's also pre-loaded with maps etc.

How do you find these high tech hotels in Hong Kong? The hotel booking sites I've looked at doesn't seem to have a filter for that. Is there any specific keyword one can use when researching this?

I'm planning to go to Hong Kong soon just to stay at a high tech hotel.

*A robot waitress in the hotel restaurant would be cool.*

Comment: Fwiw, none of those things are exclusive to Hong Kong, but it would be interesting to know how to find such services.

(some hotels also let you unlock your door with your own phone, allowing you to skip checkin desks)

Comment: I want to combine it with a trip to Hong Kong 

Answer (score 3):

L’hotel Island South sounds like one of them.  [Source](https://www.scmp.com/business/article/3078765/hong-kong-developer-chinachems-hotels-unit-brings-robots-beat-coronavirus).

> Hong Kong hotels operator L’hotel Group has turned to robots amid a
> Covid-19 driven slump in the hospitality sector, with the aim of
> providing meals to guests and ensuring reduced interaction with staff.
>
> The company, which is wholly owned by property developer Chinachem
> Group, will have three artificial intelligence robots called Genie
> delivering meals and drinks to guests at its 432-room L’hotel Island
> South property in Wong Chuk Hang, which welcomes guests in quarantine,
> by mid-April. L’hotel said it was the first hotel to introduce
> meal-delivery robots in Hong Kong.

Since you asked how to find them, I just googled "robot waiter hotel hong kong" and clicked on a couple of news stories, finding this.

Answer (score 1):

Many (but not all) Marriott hotels in Asia, including Hong Kong, now offer "**Mobile Key**" which lets you use your own phone as a key to enter the room and other amenities like gyms etc:

https://help.marriott.com/s/article/Article-22239

After inhaling Starwood, Marriott is now the largest hotel chain in the world, with brands including Westin, W, Renaissance, Sheraton, Mira for a total of 26 properties in HK.

Unfortunately Marriott makes it quite difficult to figure out *which* hotels offer this, as far as I can tell it's not listed anywhere on the public website. However, if you open up a Marriott hotel in the app, it's listed under Hotel Info > Amenities if available:

[image]

...although this, too, doesn't fully distinguish between the full contactless mobile key and just mobile check-in (which still requires you to pick up physical keys on arrival).